# jar server stopping triggers shutdown.exe

Tags: c++, windows, jar, shutdown

I want to write a c++ code to launch a java server(the file name is server.jar) and when the server is stopped I want to run shutdown.exe
I looked up how to launch the server.jar but I din't find anything comprehendible on how to detect it stopping

What I want to achieve is:

1. run script --> server starts and runs for a while
2. server recieves a stop command from client
3. server stops --> script runs shutdown.exe

Answer (score 0):

I made the code work so here it is:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
wchar_t cmdline[] = L" -jar server.jar";
//wchar_t path[] = L"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre*\\bin\\javaw.exe";

char* pathc= std::getenv("_JAVAW");
wchar_t* path;
path = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * strlen(pathc));
mbstowcs(path, pathc, strlen(pathc)+1);

if (CreateProcess( path, cmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    std::cout << "running" << std::endl;
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    wchar_t cmdline[] = L" -s -t 60";
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    if (CreateProcess(L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\shutdown.exe", cmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)) {

    }
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
return 0;
```

}